# Turning a regular into a wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

What would be the cheapest way of turning non-wireless-regular-cheap-printer (low grade inkjet) into a wireless
one without attaching a full-blown-always-on-computer-that's-on-a-wireless-network ?

All ideas welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide with a few options here at [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/make-wired-printer-wireless/12639/).

> Here are some possible scenarios:
>
> - If your current printer is relatively new and you paid more than
>     $100 for it, then it may be more
>     economical for you to simply purchase
>     a wireless print server instead of
>     purchasing an entirely new printer
>     with the same features.
> - If a wireless printer in not available in your area, you can buy a
>     regular USB based wired printer and
>     get someone to ship you a wireless
>     print server. This would incur less
>     shipping costs than ordering a
>     wireless printer.
> - Some wireless print servers can be used as wireless routers. If you do
>     not have a wireless router at your
>     place, you can opt for a wireless
>     print server as it will not only turn
>     your printer wireless but you also get
>     to setup a wireless home network.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would buy a [wireless print server that supports usb printers](http://www.google.com/products?q=wireless+print+server+usb) (but I suspect most do these days)

Answer (score 1):

Companies such as Cisco/Linksys produce wireless print servers. They can be a little pricey, but as they've been around for a while you may find cheap second-hand units on e-bay.

http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/products/PrintServers

Another possibility, if you're in the market for a network storage device, is to find one that supports usb printers, which you could then connect to your wi-fi router.

Routers typically lack sufficient memory to operate efficiently as a print server, so I suspect finding one that does is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Your current wireless router, depending on the model, might already include a wireless USB print server

Answer (score 0):

Mac solution. I can print from my wireless MacBook to my Brother wired printer. Looking at another iMac that is usb connected to the printer, enable this usb connected iMac using print sharing in system preferences. Add the Brother printer in the MacBook. Print from the MacBook! No cat!